# Unity Editor not showing labels on buttons

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity Editor not showing labels on buttons

[image: Unity Editor not showing labels on buttons !!!]

How to solve it?

Using Unity 2022.3.1fi LTS on Windows 10 PRO

Comment: Looks like your computer ran out of resources

Comment: What do you mean ?
should i download any progs or graphic Apis

Comment: Resources are not about downloads.  Usually memory leaks. Not enough memory. Low spec graphics card.  But it is not a programming issue

Comment: dummy IT comment: Have you tried restarting Unity / rebooting the PC?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it is not cause by your code (e.g. try opening it in a different computer). You can try reinstalling everything (Unity Hub, Unity). But before that, you have to do a full complete clean up. e.g. CCleaner and delete the AppData that Unity stores at different locations.